# Wrap text to a specific width within a page

Tags: html, css, asp-classic, styles

This centres the text within the page width okay, however I need to wrap the text at something like a 480px width so I don't have a long line of text

```
Params = "x=0; y=320; width="&page.width&"; alignment=center; size=18; html=true"
```

For example: currently its

```
                                    Welcome to 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
```

BUT I need it to wrap at

```
                                    Welcome to 

              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                             sed do eiusmod tempor
```

Answer (score 0):

Use non-breaking spaces:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed&nbsp;do&nbsp;eiusmod&nbsp;tempor.</p>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/avFeL/)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with my code and causes an error.  Is there something like text wrap or textoverflow???

Comment: I am currently using:  Params = "x=50; y=320; width="&table.width&"; alignment=center; size=18; html=true"  which seems to be working okay but I think is not the true correct answer?